# getting an error while trying deploy a crd using terrafom

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-custom-resources

I'm trying to deploy a crd using terraform with the code bellow

```sh
resource "kubectl_manifest" "crd-deploy" {
  for_each  = [ for crd in var.crdslist : crd ]
  yaml_body = (fileexists("${path.module}/crds/${crd}.yaml") ? file("${path.module}/crds/${crd}") : "")
}
```

but i still get an error

```sh
 Error: Invalid reference
 
   on ../../00-modules/00-global/25-crd/10-crd.tf line 3, in resource "kubectl_manifest" "crd-deploy":
    3:   yaml_body = (fileexists("${path.module}/crds/${crd}.yaml") ? file("${path.module}/crds/${crd}") : "")
 
 A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

input.tf in module_level

```sh
variable "crdslist" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = []
}
```

input.tf in execution_module_level

```sh
locals {
  crdslist            = ["crd-test"]
}
```

From where i run the terraform plan to deploy K8s CRDs

```sh
module "crds" {
  source   = "../../modules/global/25-crd"
  crdslist = local.crdslist
}
```

Comment: Try `for_each = toset(var.crdlist)`.

Comment: Converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the variable that is used is of type `list(string)`, that means it cannot be used with `for_each` in its original form. The `for_each` meta-argument requires a variable to be of type `map` or `set` [1]:

> If a resource or module block includes a for_each argument whose value is a map or a set of strings, Terraform will create one instance for each member of that map or set.

In order for the current configuration to work as expected, it is enough to use a Terraform built-in function `toset` [2]. The only change that needs to be made is inside of the module:

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "crd-deploy" {
  for_each  = toset(var.crdslist)
  yaml_body = (fileexists("${path.module}/crds/${each.vlaue}.yaml") ? file("${path.module}/crds/${each.vlaue}") : "")
}
```

Note that when the list is converted to a set, the key and value are the same, i.e., `each.key` and `each.value` can be used interchangeably [3].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/toset

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#the-each-object

Comment: so helpful, sufficient explanation, I couldn't agree more, i applied the changes, it works, Thanks :-D

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer as the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer?

Comment: yes with pleasure, what's the more efficient resource ? to use kubectl_manifest or using kubernetes_manifest ?

Comment: I tend to use the official providers whenever I can, but not sure what is more efficient.